# JUnit assertTrue is ambiguous for two strings, and test case fails for doubles

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to write a JUnit test to confirm that my variables are saving correctly. I'm having trouble passing the test cases for doubles and strings

```
@Test
public void testConstructor() {
    Flight test = new Flight(200, "Canada", "Mexico", "03/02/99 7:50 pm", 500, 10); 
    assertEquals(200, test.flightNumber);
    assertEquals(10, test.capacity);
    assertEquals(Double.valueOf(500), test.originalPrice);
    
    String a ="Canada";
    String b = test.origin;
    assertTrue(a.equals(b));
}
```

My double case seems to be failing despite the fact that both values clearly should be 500, and I getting this error for assertTrue:

> both method assertTrue(boolean) in Assert and method
> assertTrue(Boolean) in assertions match

I don't even know why it's saying boolean, shouldn't they be strings?

This is the code the test case is testing:

```
public int flightNumber, capacity, numberOfSeatsLeft;
public double originalPrice;
public String origin, destination, departureTime;

public Flight(int flightNumber, String origin, String destination, String departureTime, double originalPrice, int capacity) {
    if (destination.equals(origin)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Already at destination");
    }
    this.origin=origin;
    this.destination=destination;
    this.departureTime=departureTime;
    this.originalPrice=originalPrice;
    this.flightNumber=flightNumber;
    this.capacity=capacity;
}
```

Comment: Your tests seems to pass in my local. What JUnit version are you using? Also can you show the class fields, possibly typo in there?

Comment: @iambk I'm using Junit4, and I've added the fields!

Comment: Yep, that's the issue. The method signature you are trying to use doesn't exist in Assert class (JUnit v4). `public static void assertEquals(Double expected, double actual)` is part of JUnit v5 Assertions class.

Comment: Use JUnit v5 and use `Assertions.assertEquals` instead of `Assert.assertEquals` or try testing against `double` instead of `Double` if you wanna stick with JUnit 4

Comment: @Nik Please [edit] your question to include the full complete file content where the `testConstructor()` method is placed in.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `assertEquals(Double, double)`, a wrapper class and it's corresponding primitive counterpart, and there is no such method in junit. It's caused by your field `originalPrice` being `double`, but `Double.valueOf(500)` returns a `Double`. You should either use `assertEquals(double, double)`, but it's deprecated, or `assertEquals(Object, Object)`. You can call it like this:

```
assertEquals(Double.valueOf(500), Double.valueOf(test.originalPrice));
```